# Receive UDP packets in Async Task BackGround Process

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, udp

```
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;

        byte [] ip_bytes = new byte[] {(byte)192,(byte)168,(byte)1,(byte)100};
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip_bytes );

          byte buffer[] = new byte[2000];

                    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, port);
                    try {
                    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
                    Log.d("..........","Perfect Binding .... Waiting for Data");
                    ds.receive(p);
                    publishProgress(""+p);
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                    Log.d("","Received :) ");
                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

....................................
This is code for receiving UDP packet in Async Backgroung Process, But am not getting a single packet ... what is wrong in my code ?? How i can overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for receiving, you don't need to specify the ip and port in DatagramPacket.

```
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
```

Comment: Yes ... Thanks , Working fine now :) My case issue is I forgot to connect my mobile to wi-fi , so no ip address assigned to it. SO it was not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you explain how to receive multiple message? which modification of the code is necessary.